# Why does GHCi understand imports that GHC doesn't?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. When I'm in GHCi (using the `ghci` command), I can type `import System.Random`, and it works. I can then generate random numbers.

Next, I make a file called `test.hs` that contains nothing but one line: `import System.Random`. I then call the command `ghc test.hs` and get the following error message:

```
test.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘System.Random’
    There are files missing in the ‘random-1.1’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
1 | import System.Random
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, if I go back to GHCi, I can type `:load test.hs`. This works, and allows me to generate random numbers.

When I run `ghc-pkg check`, I get only warnings about missing haddock interface files: https://pastebin.com/6a9f0nYZ. From what I understand, this isn't related to the current issue.

Also, when I run `ghc-pkg list`, `random-1.1` is in the list, so `random` should be installed.

A couple of questions:

- Why would GHC and GHCi have access to different imports? Why is the system set up that way? Maybe I just don't understand the relationship between GHC and GHCi.
- According to the error message, there are "files missing." How can I figure out which files?
- How can I make it so that I can compile Haskell files that use `System.Random`?

---

Edit: Both GHC and GHCi are the same version.

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.4
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.4
```

---

Edit: Both `ghc` and `ghci` are in **/usr/bin/**

```
$ which ghc
/usr/bin/ghc
$ which ghci
/usr/bin/ghci
```

Comment: Are they different versions?

Comment: Both are version 8.6.4

Comment: What do `which ghc` and `which ghci` show? I imagine you may have two copies of haskell installed, one of which is broken.

Comment: @amalloy both are in `/usr/bin/`. How could I figure out if/where/how I have two copies of Haskell installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:*  It looks like this is an Arch Linux peculiarity, not a corrupt package.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

GHCi loads "dynamic" versions of modules.  By default, GHC links with "static" versions of modules.  In particular, when you run:

```
> import System.Random
```

under GHCi, it tries to access the file `Random.dyn_hi` to get interface information for the module.  In contrast, when you compile a file with that import statement in it, GHC tries to access the file `Random.hi`.

You can verify this is the issue by running `ghc-pkg field random import-dirs` and peeking in the resulting directory.  There should be a `System` subdirectory that usually has two files in it:  `System.hi` and `System.dyn_hi`.  If the former is missing, that's your problem.

Now, it looks like you're probably using Arch Linux.  As documented on the Arch [Haskell wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haskell) in the section "Problems with linking", the Arch Haskell community packages (including `haskell-random`) intentionally omit the static versions of interface files and libraries.

There are several of workarounds given there:

- You can use dynamic linking when compiling with GHC.  When using GHC directly, this just means passing the `-dynamic` flag.  For Cabal-based projects, instructions are given on that page for modifying your `~/.cabal/config` to use dynamic linking for all projects.
- You can install the `ghc-static` and `ghc-pristine` packages and set up your path and/or Cabal to use the compiler in `/usr/share/ghc-pristine/bin/ghc` which will maintain its own separate package database that won't interfere with globally installed Haskell community packages, like `haskell-random`.
- You can install `ghc-static` to get static versions of the base libraries and then run `cabal install --force-reinstalls somepackage` for all the non-base packages you need.  Note that the Wiki notes that this can be tedious and complicated, since you have to manually determine all the package dependencies.

Now, it looks like you already had `ghc-static` installed, or when invoking GHC you would have *also* gotten an error about missing files in the `base` package.  You ran `cabal install --force-reinstalls random`, though as @dfeuer notes, it might have been safer to run:

```
$ cabal install --force-reinstalls random-1.1
```

to ensure that the same version was reinstalled.

Anyway, this installed an additional copy of `random` in your user-specific package directory.  If you run:

```
$ ghc-pkg list
```

you'll see that `random-1.1` is listed both under the global database and user database:

```
/usr/lib/ghc-8.6.4/package.conf.d
    ...
    random-1.1
    ...
/home/xxxx/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.6.4/package.conf.d
    random-1.1
```

and if you run:

```
$ ghc-pkg describe random
```

you'll see that it lists the two separate installed versions which is why you now get duplicate fields with `ghc-pkg field random import-dirs`.

There shouldn't be anything wrong with this.  Your user database will take precedence over the global database, so your newly installed version of `random` will be used when you run GHCi or GHC.

Note that, if you change your mind and want to back out this reinstallation (and maybe try one of the other solutions suggested on the Wiki), you should be able to run:

```
$ ghc-pkg unregister --user random
```

Technically, this won't actually remove the package (as the compiled version will still be there under `~/.cabal/lib`), but it should otherwise put things back the way they were.

Comment: To avoid breakage, you might want to specify the same version of the package that's already installed.

Comment: You're spot-on that `Random.dyn_hi` exists but `Random.hi` doesn't. I ran the command `cabal install --force-reinstall random`, and now I'm able to compile files that import `System.Random` using the `ghc` command. However, now when I run `ghc-pkg field random import-dirs`, I two lines of output: `import-dirs: /home/finn/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.6.4/random-1.1-3ypV4EIycgb35PKjTYYr5q` and `import-dirs: /usr/lib/ghc-8.6.4/site-local/random-1.1`. Is it a problem that it now exists in two places? Should I uninstall one of them?

Comment: It looks like this is an Arch Linux peculiarity.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that Arch was relevant, which is why I didn't even mention it, so I'm impressed that you were able to identify the issue despite my incomplete information. I couldn't ask for a better answer, and in the future, I'll use dynamic linking.